# Bit shift resulting in zero when it shouldn't

Tags: go

I'm developing a Chip8 emulator.  Chip8 instructions are stored as two byte pairs, which I handle as a uint16.  The data for the opcodes is interwoven into the opcode itself.  For example the opcode to draw a sprite is 0xDxyn, where the opcode is actually just 0xD000, with the last three places being the x and y location to draw, and the n being how many bytes the sprite is.

This is mind, I've been trying to extract this data using simple bitshifting and masking, but I keep getting 0 instead of the expected values.  For example:

```
//Opcode is = 0xD01F, of type uint16
x := int(c.Registers[((opcode >> 16) & 0x000F)])
y := int(c.Registers[((opcode >> 8) & 0x000F)])
size := int((opcode & 0x000F))
```

This should resolve to c.Registers[0] and c.Registers[1], instead both end up c.Registers[0].  Size comes out correctly 15.  Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you shift a 16 bit number 16 places to the right you've shifted all of the data out.

To get x you need to shift 8 bits and to get y, 4 bits. (Remember: each hex digit is 4 bits)

Comment: For some reason I had it in my head to shift 8 places for each hex digit.  What a doofus.